# Enabling CSP unsafe-eval support on other origins

Tags: lightning, google-map, content-security-policy, lightning-container, csp

I'm trying to build a component utilising lightning:component (external build) which has a dependency that loads code on init via a script tag. Specifically I'm trying to load content from https://maps.googleapis.com

I've followed https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_csp.htm and put the following in my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "landing-pages" : [
        {
            "path": "index.html",
            "content-security-policy-type": "custom",
            "content-security-policy": "default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' maps.googleapis.com fonts.googleapis.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

It appears as though the unsafe-inline statement works for fonts.googleapis.com, however the unsafe-eval for maps.googleapis.com doesn't work. Does lightning reject some of the custom CSP I have supplied?

Side note: I'll update the sources to `https://maps.googleapis.com` for example once I get this working, but for now I thought I'd let it be open just incase it causes other issues.

Apart from this, has anyone else had any luck with embedding google maps inside lightning? I haven't tried a VF solution yet, but want to avoid for legacy sake, and I feel the CSP would stop this anyway. Also, am tempted to raise a case with SF for this, but don't want to spend weeks getting the run around.